# How to access Navigation Bar from a View Controller of a subview ?

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have a View Controller where I select some data into an array and then optionally on clicking of a button I show that data in a TableView added as a subview to previous view with a flip animation.

Now I have the facility to delete data from array I have picked from first view and passed to this one.

Now I have a condition that there is a button on the righthand side on the navigationBar on whose controller the previous view was pushed.

Now that button needs to be disabled until there r atleast X number of  elements in the array.
so while I am adding data In my previous view, I keep check on the array and as soon it crosses the required count , I enable the button.

Now in the other view which is a TableView which has been brought in with animation,
Whenever I delete data I need to disable the button again when it goes below the number X.

How can I access the navigationBar's button in this subview's controller ?
shall I set the first view Controller as delegate in the next one ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your viewController is inside UINavigationViewController, you can set navigationBar buttons with `self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem` and `self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem`.

Comment: I wish it was but I have just presented it with a flip animation.
I guess I have no option left but to use a delegate to inform the parent view's controller to disable the navigationBar.

Answer (score 0):

try using superView proprty or loop through all the pushed ViewController and check if it is previous VC. Then make the button enabled or disabled

Answer (score 0):

My opinion is you can create a uinavigationController object in your subview and assign it from your parent view(Where you have the navigation controller object). You can then access the navigation controller in the subview.